# Continuous micro-freezing in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: kernel, touchpad

Since a couple of months I experience continuous freezings of my system (Dell XPS 13 2014, i7, Ubuntu 14.04). If I am not mistaken, they first appeared at a time when the fans of my laptop broke down, so the system would randomly freeze (and stayed frozen). Now I've replaced the fans and the "total freezings" have disappeared; but I still experience very, very annoying micro-freezings (~½ second): usual work is not affected too much, but watching a youtube video or listening to spotify has become virtually impossible; I can't understand whether this is an issue of BIOS, CPU, or Ubuntu.

Let me copy and paste the syslog from the last 30 minutes or so: the fact that my trackpad loses sync so often looks to me like a symptom, not the cause of the freezings.

```
Oct 27 10:45:18 delio-xps kernel: [34341.874179] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 3 bytes away.

Oct 27 10:45:43 delio-xps kernel: [34366.893892] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 4 bytes away.

Oct 27 10:46:05 delio-xps anacron[16208]: Job `cron.daily' terminated

Oct 27 10:46:05 delio-xps anacron[16208]: Normal exit (1 job run)

Oct 27 10:47:18 delio-xps kernel: [34461.961207] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 2 bytes away.

Oct 27 10:48:33 delio-xps kernel: [34537.004388] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 4 bytes away.

Oct 27 10:48:48 delio-xps kernel: [34552.012241] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 1 bytes away.

Oct 27 10:49:08 delio-xps kernel: [34572.027774] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 4 bytes away.

Oct 27 10:49:13 delio-xps kernel: [34577.027337] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 1 bytes away.

Oct 27 10:49:53 delio-xps kernel: [34617.058832] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 2 bytes away.

Oct 27 10:50:01 delio-xps CRON[20916]: (root) CMD (pkill -f indicator-power-service)

Oct 27 10:50:08 delio-xps kernel: [34632.062841] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 3 bytes away.

Oct 27 10:50:45 delio-xps wpa_supplicant[1740]: message repeated 4 times: [ wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED ]

Oct 27 10:51:14 delio-xps wpa_supplicant[1740]: wlan0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with c8:0e:14:42:80:c3 [GTK=CCMP]

Oct 27 10:51:28 delio-xps kernel: [34712.232648] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 2 bytes away.

Oct 27 10:51:43 delio-xps kernel: [34727.131013] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 4 bytes away.

Oct 27 10:52:45 delio-xps wpa_supplicant[1740]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 

Oct 27 10:53:37 delio-xps AptDaemon: INFO: Quitting due to inactivity

Oct 27 10:53:37 delio-xps AptDaemon: INFO: Quitting was requested

Oct 27 10:53:37 delio-xps dbus[823]: [system] Activating service name='org.debian.apt' (using servicehelper)

Oct 27 10:53:38 delio-xps AptDaemon: INFO: Initializing daemon

Oct 27 10:53:38 delio-xps dbus[823]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.debian.apt'

Oct 27 10:53:38 delio-xps AptDaemon.PackageKit: INFO: Initializing PackageKit compat layer

Oct 27 10:53:48 delio-xps kernel: [34852.205928] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 2 bytes away.

Oct 27 10:53:53 delio-xps kernel: [34857.210236] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 3 bytes away.

Oct 27 10:55:13 delio-xps kernel: [34937.266946] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 3 bytes away.

Oct 27 10:55:38 delio-xps kernel: [34962.283382] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 5 bytes away.

Oct 27 10:56:38 delio-xps kernel: [35022.316427] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 1 bytes away.

Oct 27 10:56:43 delio-xps kernel: [35027.321602] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 2 bytes away.

Oct 27 10:57:23 delio-xps kernel: [35067.341895] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 2 bytes away.

Oct 27 10:59:03 delio-xps kernel: [35167.408092] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 1 bytes away.

Oct 27 10:59:08 delio-xps kernel: [35172.411130] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 5 bytes away.

Oct 27 10:59:13 delio-xps kernel: [35177.417869] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 5 bytes away.

Oct 27 11:00:01 delio-xps CRON[22618]: (root) CMD (pkill -f indicator-power-service)

Oct 27 11:00:45 delio-xps wpa_supplicant[1740]: message repeated 4 times: [ wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED ]

Oct 27 11:01:14 delio-xps wpa_supplicant[1740]: wlan0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with c8:0e:14:42:80:c3 [GTK=CCMP]

Oct 27 11:02:45 delio-xps wpa_supplicant[1740]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 

Oct 27 11:03:39 delio-xps AptDaemon: INFO: Quitting due to inactivity

Oct 27 11:03:39 delio-xps AptDaemon: INFO: Quitting was requested

Oct 27 11:03:39 delio-xps dbus[823]: [system] Activating service name='org.debian.apt' (using servicehelper)

Oct 27 11:03:40 delio-xps AptDaemon: INFO: Initializing daemon

Oct 27 11:03:40 delio-xps dbus[823]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.debian.apt'

Oct 27 11:03:40 delio-xps AptDaemon.PackageKit: INFO: Initializing PackageKit compat layer

Oct 27 11:05:09 delio-xps sudo: pam_ecryptfs: pam_sm_authenticate: /home/delio is already mounted

Oct 27 11:06:08 delio-xps kernel: [35592.683473] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 5 bytes away.

Oct 27 11:09:28 delio-xps kernel: [35792.924462] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 1 bytes away.

Oct 27 11:10:01 delio-xps CRON[24386]: (root) CMD (pkill -f indicator-power-service)

Oct 27 11:10:38 delio-xps kernel: [35862.856827] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 3 bytes away.

Oct 27 11:10:43 delio-xps kernel: [35867.863068] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 4 bytes away.

Oct 27 11:11:08 delio-xps kernel: [35892.876810] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 4 bytes away.

Oct 27 11:10:45 delio-xps wpa_supplicant[1740]: message repeated 4 times: [ wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED ]

Oct 27 11:11:14 delio-xps wpa_supplicant[1740]: wlan0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with c8:0e:14:42:80:c3 [GTK=CCMP]

Oct 27 11:12:45 delio-xps wpa_supplicant[1740]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 

Oct 27 11:13:40 delio-xps AptDaemon: INFO: Quitting due to inactivity

Oct 27 11:13:40 delio-xps AptDaemon: INFO: Quitting was requested

Oct 27 11:13:58 delio-xps kernel: [36062.990345] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 3 bytes away.

Oct 27 11:14:03 delio-xps kernel: [36067.995912] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 2 bytes away.
```

Comment: The "psmouse" driver throwing bytes away message is interesting. Did you Google that?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I tried, but it was of no use (or I was googling it the wrong way): this very post was the fourth result.